# generate random number of arithmetic progression in c programming

Tags: c

Here is my code right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{ 
    float r;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX*20;
    printf("%.1f\n",r);


   return(0);
}
```

The code can work to generate a random number with decimal from 0 -20 but I want to generate a number like 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5...19.5,20.0.

What should I add into my program?

Comment: That is not verry random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the random number as an `int` and generate it between 1 and 40. Then divide by 2.0 to get the numbers you want.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{ 
    float r;
    int n;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        n = rand() % 40 + 1;  // Gives random values 1, 2, …, 39, 40
        r = n/2.0;            // Divide by floating point 2 to get 0.5, 1.0, .. 20.0
        printf("%.1f\n",r);
    }

   return(0);
}
```

that should give you the values 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, …., 19.5, 20.0

Sample output:

```
14.0
0.5
11.0
4.5
15.0
8.0
19.5
18.0
19.0
6.0
```

Comment: In general, `rand() % 40 + 1` does not provide a uniform distribution. If `RAND_MAX` is set to 32767, then numbers in [1, 7] are returned with a probability 820/32767, while numbers in [8, 40] with 819/32767.

Comment: @Giovanni It's true that `rand` in it's basic form doesn't provide a uniform distribution but... Do you real think that's what OP is concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random number between `a` and `b` inclusive, with `n` different, uniformly spaced, possible values:

```
 value = a + ((b - a) / (n - 1)) * (rand() % n);
```

So for 0.5, 1.0 ..., 20.0, use `a = 0.5, b = 20.0, n = 40`.

In general beware of *modulo bias* when using this approach; but `rand()` isn't a good enough generator for this to matter anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{ 
    float r;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX*20;
    d = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX*1;
    if (d == 1) {
        r = r + 0.5;
    }
    printf("%.1f\n",r);


   return(0);
}
```

or if you want numbers like 2.3 or 5.4 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{ 
    float r;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX*200;
    r /= 10;
    printf("%.1f\n",r);


   return(0);
}
```

Comment: 1st code does not compile, Amended with `float d;`, it generates values like 13.1, 9.7 (not part of OP's goal), and significantly does not create 20.0 uniformly.